# my earphones won't work on my nokia lumia 630

Tags: nokia-lumia-630

Well at first I had problem when I put my earphones on the sound goes low by itself and I can't get it loud. But I fixed it .however, now when I put my earphones on they won't work at all and I hear the normal phone sound ,yet when I try and other earphones it works normally and when I try my earphones in an other phone it also works normally (in conclusion my earphones doesn't work with my Nokia Lumia 630)

Comment: What connector do the headphones that don't work have? - does it have four rings, or three?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the earphones you're trying to use are incompatible with your phone. This usually happens when your earphones are not originally from the device manufacturer (Microsoft, or Nokia). In the case of the sound going down by itself, it's because the earphones probably have a volume control function, due to the incompatibility, that is automatically triggered when you connect them to your phone's 3.5mm jack.
I would advise you find other earphones, and stop forcing these ones to work on your phone, as you might end up destroying your phone's earphones jack. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue once.  Turns out that there was a small button near the volume control on the headphones.  Pressed that and no problems ever since.

I did not need to do this with any other phone/laptop.